# Java ArrayList of ArrayLists behaving weird when adding objects

Tags: java, arraylist, addition

I'm trying to add Objects ( in this example to keep it simple Strings) to Arraylists, that are collected as an Arraylist. Here is the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList dummylist = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dummylistlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    for (int j=0; j< 2; j++){
      dummylistlist.add(dummylist);
      String text = "test";
      dummylistlist.get(j).add(text);
    }

    for (int j=0; j< 2; j++){
      System.out.println("arraylist "+j+" has size "+dummylistlist.get(j).size());
      System.out.println("Arraylist No."+j+" is ="+dummylistlist.get(j));
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
arraylist 0 has size 2
Arraylist No.0 is =[test, test]
arraylist 1 has size 2
Arraylist No.1 is =[test, test]
```

But I expected it to be:

```
arraylist 0 has size 1
Arraylist No.0 is =[test]
arraylist 1 has size 1
Arraylist No.1 is =[test]
```

Why does the method add(text) appends the "test" String to all sublists so that it gets added once each loop? I don't understand. Can you help me to fix my code to achieve the latter output? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't call `dummylistlist.add(dummylist);` You have only one list because of this, called `dummylist`.

Comment: You're adding the same list twice into your "listlist" and because of this, adding "test" twice into `dummylist`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're creating only one list which you put into the other. Thus, when calling `get(j)`, you're always retrieving the same inner list and adding the element to it. If you want distinct lists, create them inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work, you need to initialize `dummylist` variable inside the `for` loop 
Since you have only one instance of `dummylist` inside your code, it is the same reference that you are adding at each loop iteration. That is why you need to create a new instance of `ArrayList` at each loop iteration